# Long Usernames cause issues with the theme

Tags: bug, design

If an unregistered user's name is long enough, it will cause the network profile and mod links to wrap to a second, hidden line. You can access this line by drag-selecting the username down, but there is no scroll-bar.

For example, see the user account that I created for this purpose:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/22132/long-usernames-cause-wordwraps

Below is an image that illustrates the differences between a long username, and a short username.

[image]

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Everything seems fine here. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: What are 'mod links'? Network profile is on the same line when I see it. Perhaps it only wraps for the user when he is logged in, and not to other users?

Comment: @CamilStaps I believe it may only be a bug for moderators. Sorry you can't enjoy this one too ;)

Comment: [I don't see any wordwrap](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s11/sh/c11030cb-d231-4085-8be9-023ae9ea02d2/3174ccd3952502156374bc29eb55d3e3): can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Looks fine to me too.  However, anyone that creates a user name that absurdly long deserves to have it get truncated and look stupid.  Don't do that (duh).

Comment: @Sklivvz It's actually showing in your screenshot. See my annotated screenshot.

Comment: @OlinLathrop there already is a maximum length of 30. I think it would be better to adapt the theme to that maximum.

Comment: By the way, this isn't only a bug for moderators, you can see it yourself when giving your own profile a very long name.

Answer (score 4):

I've limited the display size of the user name in that page to 400px.

[image]

It will be rolled out in the next build.

Comment: Hrm... now the line wrap appears to be happening much more frequently - on most EE.SE users now. Oddly enough, the meta.EE.SE accounts look mostly fine.

Comment: Typo :-) Should be fixed shortly.

Comment: @Sklivvz unintended feature, W5VO did not make a clear request, but if you have to you will change it again. :)

Comment: This bug has reoccured

Comment: Still a bug, please come fix [me](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/25395/koretek-is-a-newb-to-me). :)

Comment: Now the bug [has gone global!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203354/mod-links-disappear-on-profiles-with-long-display-names)